# Similarity measure in Spacy tokens

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to measure the similarity between tokens. I am using the default en model. The similarity measure works as expected when using singular nouns but returns zero when using the same nouns in plural.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp('apple orange')
doc[0].similarity(doc[1])
```

returns 0.56189166448170025

```
doc = nlp('apples oranges')
doc[0].similarity(doc[1])
```

returns 0.0

Are there any preprocessing steps I need to implement for the measure to work correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Please can you specify which version of spacy do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't have support phrasal similarity; a hacky alternative is to tokenize your phrase, where its score would be average of the similarities of each token. Alternatively you can use the phrasal similarity [here](https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/similarity).